# g++ unable to link with libboost_date_time

Tags: boost, linker, g++

So I suspect this is due to my recently making and installing gcc-7.3.0 on my system (ubuntu 14.04). This used to work but now it no longer does and I really can't figure out why.
Any suggestions would be very welcomed.

Thanks:
Dan

g++-7.3.0 doesn't compile

```
dan@chicabuntu:~/RNN/GAForest$ g++  -o validateStemForest validateStemsForest.o prog.o loadSequences.o stem.o stemBinder.o   -std=c++11 -DRANDSOURCE=7 -lm -lgomp  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu  -lboost_date_time

validateStemsForest.o: In function `unsigned short boost::date_time::month_str_to_ushort<boost::gregorian::greg_month>(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
validateStemsForest.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost9date_time19month_str_to_ushortINS_9gregorian10greg_monthEEEtRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[_ZN5boost9date_time19month_str_to_ushortINS_9gregorian10greg_monthEEEtRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0xab): undefined reference to `boost::gregorian::greg_month::get_month_map_ptr[abi:cxx11]()'
```

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

However, I have the correct libraries:

```
dan@chicabuntu:~/RNN/GAForest$ ls -ltrh /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_date_time.*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   28 Jun 21  2014 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_date_time.so -> libboost_date_time.so.1.54.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  67K Jun 21  2014 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_date_time.so.1.54.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 143K Jun 21  2014 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_date_time.a
```

And the libraries have the functions I'm trying to link to

```
dan@chicabuntu:~/RNN/GAForest$ nm -D /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_date_time.so| grep get_month_map_ptr
0000000000008960 T _ZN5boost9gregorian10greg_month17get_month_map_ptrEv
```

And the libraries are in the path

```
dan@chicabuntu:~/RNN/GAForest$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/:/usr/local/cuda/lib64::/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/nvidia-375:/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/nvidia-375:/usr/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Here is the version of g++ and boost that I'm using:

```
dan@chicabuntu:~/RNN/GAForest$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.3.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../gcc-7.3.0/configure --disable-multilib
 Thread model: posixqqw
gcc version 7.3.0 (GCC)

dan@chicabuntu:~/RNN/GAForest$ dpkg -S /usr/include/boost/version.hpp
libboost1.54-dev: /usr/include/boost/version.hp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[abi:cxx11] on the end of the undefined symbol is possibly a clue.
New versions of gcc have a different ABI to support c++11: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html. If your boost libraries were compiled with the old ABI they wont link with code compiled with the new ABI.

Try building your code with `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0`

Comment: This was the issue - thanks so much! D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 fixed the compilation and D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1 broke it again, proving that this was the problem. Very much appreciate your help!

Comment: @Dan Welcome to Stackoverflow! Great that your problem is solved. Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)